# How do I change the background image of a span based on its content?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wonder if somebody can help with this. I am trying to change the background image of a span based on its content. I've spent a few days Googling this and not been able to come up with anything.

The HTML is structured like this:

```
<span id="foo" class="bar">
    Gallery
</span>
```

And, once the span has been clicked, it changes to:

```
<span id="foo" class="bar">
    List
</span>
```

I've had a *go* with jQuery and come up with this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("span#foo").each(function() {
        var $el = $(this);
        var image;
        var content = $el.text().toLowerCase();
        if (content.indexOf("gallery") !== -1) {
            image = "url(http://www.example.co.uk/images/foursquares.png) 14px 6px / 10px 10px no-repeat";
        }
        else if (content.indexOf("list") !== -1) {
            image = "url(http://www.example.co.uk/images/threelines.png) 14px 6px / 10px 10px no-repeat";
        }
        if (image) {
            console.log("if");
            .css("background", image);
        }
    }); 
});
```

(which I've copied and edited from another post where the author wanted to change a adjoining div's background colour, but I can't find it again) but it doesn't do anything.

Any help that anyone could provide with this would be much appreciated.

With kind regards,

Mark

Comment: `$("span#foo").each` ? You should not have duplicate IDs. IDs should be unique.

Comment: If you replace `each` by `click`, what do you have??? Andf btw, this `.css("background", image);` doesn't make sense

Comment: @A.Wolff: look like OP already have click event for span. which is toggling text Gallery and List

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Ya but his question is missing context for sure and so i'm quite too lazy to try to find any better workaround

Comment: Would it matter if the background changed on click, or would you like the background to change depending on what text is in the span?

Comment: I would like the background to change depending on what text is in the span, if possible. Also, the `span id="foo"` is unique as the content is only different after the span has been clicked and the user taken to a different page, displaying a Gallery/List view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, add a toLowerCase() function to your if statements then change "background" to "background-image"

```
$(window).load(function(){
$("span#foo").each(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var image;
    var content = $el.text().toLowerCase();
    if (content.toLowerCase().indexOf("gallery") !== -1) {
        image = "url(http://www.example.co.uk/images/foursquares.png) 14px 6px / 10px 10px no-repeat";
    }
    else if (content.toLowerCase().indexOf("list") !== -1) {
        image = "url(http://www.example.co.uk/images/threelines.png) 14px 6px / 10px 10px no-repeat";
    }
    if (image) {
        console.log("if");
        $el.css("background-image", image);
    }
}); 
});
```

Comment: You probably mean: `$el.css("background-image", image);`

Comment: Hello, and thanks for the rapid responses from everyone. I've entered @dresdain answer but the line `console.log("if");` seems to be showing an error. To give the question some context, I'm styling up an eBay store for a customer and wanting to alter the background of the toggle Gallery/List, rather than use the text to let the customer know which view they're currently seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Thank-you to all those who have helped. Probably due to my own ineptitude, I couldn't get the above answer to work, so went for a simpler option...

Rather than alter the background image, based on the span's content, I decided to alter the HTML based on its content, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('span#foo:contains("Gallery")')
        .html('<img src="http://www.example.co.uk/images/foursquares.png"');        
    $('span#foo:contains("List")')
        .html('<img src="http://www.example.co.uk/images/threelines.png"');
})
```

With kind regards,

Mark